# Combinar dos dataframes para rellenar los datos faltantes de uno con los datos del otro

Tags: r, date, bucles, dataframe, posix

Buenas querida comunidad, apelo a sus conocimientos ya que estoy estancado en lo mismo hace varios dias y no encuentro la forma de resolverlo.

Estoy trabajando con los siguientes dataframes: **XVII_10min**

```
> str(XVII_10min)
'data.frame':   52560 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ fecha_hora: POSIXct, format: "2017-01-01 00:00:00" "2017-01-01 00:10:00" "2017-01-01 00:20:00" "2017-01-01 00:30:00" ...
> head(XVII_10min)
           fecha_hora
1 2017-01-01 00:00:00
2 2017-01-01 00:10:00
3 2017-01-01 00:20:00
4 2017-01-01 00:30:00
5 2017-01-01 00:40:00
6 2017-01-01 00:50:00
```

y **prueba**

```
> str(prueba)
'data.frame':   24422 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ fecha_hora   : POSIXct, format: "2017-08-04 20:20:00" "2017-08-04 20:30:00" "2017-08-04 20:40:00" "2017-08-04 20:50:00" ...
 $ precipitacion: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
> head(prueba)
           fecha_hora precipitacion
1 2017-08-04 20:20:00             0
2 2017-08-04 20:30:00             0
3 2017-08-04 20:40:00             0
4 2017-08-04 20:50:00             0
5 2017-08-04 21:00:00             0
6 2017-08-04 21:10:00             0
```

**XVII_10min** tiene solo una variable *fecha_hora* , la cual es una secuencia POSIXct de todo el año 2017 cada 10 minutos. **prueba** tiene dos variables *fecha_hora* y *precipitacion*, la primera es una secuencia POSIXct del año 2017 cada 10 minutos, sin embargo, hay horas faltantes o incluso días, es decir, en esta variable a veces se saltan minutos, horas o incluso dias enteros del año 2017.

Mi objetivo es agregar los datos (horas) faltantes a `prueba$fecha_hora`; por ejemplo si antes tenía

```
            fecha_hora precipitacion
5  2017-08-04 21:00:00             0
6  2017-08-04 21:10:00             0
7  2017-08-04 21:30:00             0
8  2017-08-04 21:40:00             0
9  2017-08-04 21:50:00             0
```

(donde claramente falta el dato **2017-08-04 21:20:00** en la secuencia), mi objetivo es obtener:

```
            fecha_hora precipitacion
5  2017-08-04 21:00:00             0
6  2017-08-04 21:10:00             0
7  2017-08-04 21:20:00            NA
8  2017-08-04 21:30:00             0
9  2017-08-04 21:40:00             0
10 2017-08-04 21:50:00             0
```

Donde asignaré **NA** como valor a `prueba$precipitacion` en las filas donde agregue observaciones a `prueba$fecha_hora`.

Para lograr esto estoy tratando de rellenar los datos faltantes de `prueba$fecha_hora` con los datos de  `XVII_10min$fecha_hora` ya que estos sí estan completos.
Estoy procediendo de la siguiente manera (donde **a** es el nuevo dataframe creado):

```
a <- data.frame(fecha_hora = POSIXct(0), precipitacion = numeric(0))

for(i in nrow(XVII_10min)) {
  cat ("ESTAMOS EN LA FILA: ", i)
  print ("\n\n")
  for(j in nrow(prueba)) {
    if(XVII_10min[i, 1] == prueba[j, 1]) {
      a[i, 1] = prueba[j, 1]
      a[i, 2] = prueba[j, 2]
    } 
  } else if (prueba[ , 1] == any(XVII_10min[i ,1] ) == FALSE){
    a[i, 1] = XVII_10min[i, 1]
    a[i, 2] = NA
  }
}
```

Pero obtengo lo siguiente:

```
> str(a)
'data.frame':   52560 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ fecha_hora   : POSIXct, format: NA NA NA NA ...
 $ precipitacion: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
> tail(a)
               fecha_hora precipitacion
52555                <NA>            NA
52556                <NA>            NA
52557                <NA>            NA
52558                <NA>            NA
52559                <NA>            NA
52560 2017-12-31 23:50:00            NA
```

De las 52560 observaciones del dataframe creado (**a**), solamente la última adopta el valor deseado en `a$fecha_hora`, mientras que todas las observaciones en `a$precipitacion` quedaron como **NA**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que lo que debes hacer es pasar la variable `precipitacion` del data.frame b al a.

Esto lo puedes lograr en R fácilmente con la función `dplyr::left_join()`.

```
dplyr::left_join(XVII_10min, prueba, by = "fecha_hora")
```

El by es opcional, en este enlace podrás ver más al respecto. https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html

Si prefieres `r-base` mira la función `merge` también te serviría para lo que quieres hacer.